# php regex replace [a-z]+2 into $0-$0

Tags: php, regex

I have problem now, I was struggling to solve this regex issue, I already spent 2 hours for this.

```
Text: what2 when2 not3 not 2 not 2018 not2not
Expected: what-what when-when not3 not 2 not 2018 not2not
```

I want to replace every word that contains *`[alphabet]+ number(2)`* in the end of word. And then I will replace **[text]2** into **[text]-[text]**

[Here is my regex](https://regex101.com/r/Oexqia/1). My final script:

```
$str = 'what2 when2 not3 not 2 not 2018 not2not';
echo preg_replace('/[a-z]+2/i', "$0-$0", $str);
//result: what2-what2 when2-when2 not3 not 2 not 2018 not2-not2not
//expected:  what-what when-when not3 not 2 not 2018 not2not
```

My mistake is:

1. My regex still includes `not2not` which shouldn't be included
2. I can't replace `number(2)` from my matched return (`$0`). I try `$1` and `$2` but still can't solve the problem.

Did I miss anything? I'm very bad at regex actually but always want to try learn it.

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `preg_replace` function to:

```
echo preg_replace('/([a-z]+)2/i', "$1-$1", $str);
```

The `$0` means to replace the *entire* match. If you want just the word without the trailing `2` put capturing parenthesis around it by doing `/([a-z]+)2/i` then use `$1` to grab just that capture. Or in other words the word without the `2` at the end. This returns:

```
what-what when-when not3 not 2 not 2018 not-notnot
```

Next the final `not-notnot` is because your not looking for a space or end of the string. So it captures the `not2` in `not2not`. To fix that you can check for a word boundary afterwards by changing it to: `/([a-z]+)2\b/i`. The `\b` checks for both white space and end of line to capture strings like `'what2 yes2'` correctly.

Comment: damn, its so hard to learn regex, cz really hard to find book/tutorial about advance regex (not basic). Anyway, thank you so much for your explaination, this help me alot for learning regex. But i need to check MrSmile answer, because he is the first one. Thanks for this awesome explaination.

Comment: @plonknimbuzz Thanks! Unfortunately giving explanations takes time :P. Anyways I made a small edit to recommend using `\b` rather than `\s`, because `\s` won't work when the words on the end of the string.

Comment: @plonknimbuzz If your interested regular expressions came from Theoretical Computer Science on defining regular languages. But the basics is that's it's simply a way to match patterns in strings.

Comment: lol. i just want to say that about last word not works. `\s` any single whitespace , `\b` word boundary. damn i just know the `\b`. yeah.. i think i will buy book for advancing regex, cz 6 years learn PHP but still cant mastering regex. thats why i doing some test case. thank you so much. you are really kind person bro

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this solution:

```
$str = 'what2 when2 not3 not 2 not 2018 not2not';
echo preg_replace('/([a-z]+)2\s/i', "$1-$1 ", $str);

// OUTPUT:   what-what when-when not3 not 2 not 2018 not2not
//expected:  what-what when-when not3 not 2 not 2018 not2not
```

The `\s` used to found full words, but not 2 in the middle of word. 
If you won't use it, you'll have a wrong last replace (not2not). But in this way, you should add space in subject `("$1-$1 ")`

Comment: i think i need learn harder now. thanks man, your explaination is really helpfull for me.